# How to update the delete user confirmation form?

Tags: customization, users, core-modifications, wp-delete-post

I want to update the confirmation form for `delete user`.

If user has posts, it shows `Attribute all content to` - option to reassign other author for his posts.
It takes lots-of time to load the page, if there are thousands of users in the system. (we have 55k+ users)

So, I want to change the User option (`Attribute all content to`) from Drop-down to Type and Search.

I've tried to found the hooks/action but could not found that I want. I don't want to update wordpress core files to change this.

Please suggest me hooks/action for my question.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Have you already solved this?

Comment: @SallyCJ I don't think so. do you have solution for this yet?

Comment: The form has not the option to remove or change this field. So add a custom filed via hook `delete_user_form` and remove the default select via JavaScript.

Comment: @MaulikVora (and @HasmukhKalsariya), try the solution in my answer? :) I hope it works for you!

Comment: @SallyCJ I will try and let you know the answer, thanks so much

Comment: Hi there @HasmukhKalsariya, can't wait to hear from you! :)

Comment: @SallyCJ.

I Appreciate your answer, it's exactly what I want.

Thank you so much

Comment: I'm glad it helped, @HasmukhKalsariya :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the `Users` (`wp-admin/users.php`) page, WordPress uses [`wp_dropdown_users()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dropdown_users/) to generate the users drop-down menu you're referring to, so I'd suggest using the [`wp_dropdown_users_args` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_dropdown_users_args/) to filter the users *query*, e.g. to show only 1 result (or 10, but surely not 55k!) and then use JavaScript to add/load the other results.

So in this answer, I'm going to show you how you can do that, where we use [*Select2*](https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax) to add the "type and search" functionality. Note that I'm using a custom REST API endpoint which returns the results in the format expected by *Select2* and that way, the JavaScript part/code would also be simpler for us (i.e. the code is shorter).

**Step #1: Filter the users query for the `reassign_user` drop-down menu.**

```php
function my_filter_reassign_user_query( $query_args, $parsed_args ) {
    // Make sure we're on the users.php page on the admin side.
    if ( is_admin() && 'users' === get_current_screen()->id          &&
        // .. and the action is deleting a user
        ( isset( $_GET['action'] ) && 'delete' === $_GET['action'] ) &&
        // .. and the <select>'s name is set to reassign_user.
        'reassign_user' === $parsed_args['name']
    ) {
        // You can also use 10, etc., but the point is, we don't want 55k (or
        // LOTS OF) <option> tags!
        $query_args['number'] = 1;
    }

    return $query_args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_dropdown_users_args', 'my_filter_reassign_user_query', 10, 2 );
```

**Step #2: Enqueue the `Select2` scripts and styles, and our AJAX script.**

```php
function my_enqueue_select2_scripts() {
    // Make sure we're on the users.php page on the admin side.
    if ( is_admin() && 'users' === get_current_screen()->id ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'select2', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.12/css/select2.min.css', [], null );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'select2', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.12/js/select2.full.min.js', [], null );

        wp_enqueue_script( 'users-ajax', '/path/to/users-ajax.js', [ 'select2', 'jquery' ], '1.0' );
        wp_localize_script( 'users-ajax', 'users_ajax', [
            'root'  => esc_url_raw( get_rest_url() ),
            'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' ),
        ] );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_select2_scripts' );
```

**Step #3: Register the custom REST API endpoint.**

I'm just giving you the code, so check out the official [handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/) if you haven't. You'd also want to check [`WP_User_Query::prepare_query()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/prepare_query/) for the parameters you can use.

```php
function my_select2_users( $request ) {
    $search   = $request->get_param( 'term' );     // the search keyword
    $per_page = $request->get_param( 'per_page' ); // results per page
    $page     = $request->get_param( 'page' );     // current page number

    $per_page = $per_page ? $per_page : 10;
    $page     = $page     ? $page     : 1;
    $args     = [
        'number'         => $per_page,
        'paged'          => $page,
        'search_columns' => [ 'user_login', 'display_name' ],
        'fields'         => [ 'ID', 'display_name', 'user_login' ],
        'who'            => 'authors',
    ];

    if ( $search ) {
        $args['search'] = '*' . sanitize_text_field( $search ) . '*';
    }

    $query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

    $items = [];
    foreach ( $query->get_results() as $user ) {
        $items[] = [
            'id'   => $user->ID,
            'text' => $user->display_name . ' (' . $user->user_login . ')',
        ];
    }

    return [
        'results'    => $items,
        'pagination' => [ 'more' => $page * $per_page < $query->get_total() ],
        'total'      => $query->get_total(),
    ];
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    // You should rename the my-plugin to a meaningful one..
    register_rest_route( 'my-plugin/v1', '/select2_users', [
        'methods'             => 'GET',
        'callback'            => 'my_select2_users',
        'permission_callback' => function () {
            return current_user_can( 'delete_users' );
        }
    ] );
} );
```

**Step #4: The JavaScript/AJAX script (placed in `users-ajax.js`).**

Check [here](https://select2.org/configuration/options-api) for the *Select2*'s parameters (like the `ajax`) you can use.

```js
jQuery( function ( $ ) {
    $( 'select[name="reassign_user"]' ).on( 'select2:open', function () {
        $( '#delete_option1' ).prop( 'checked', true );
    } ).on( 'select2:select', function( e ) {
        $( '#submit' ).removeProp( 'disabled' );
    } ).on( 'select2:unselect', function( e ) {
        $( '#submit' ).prop( 'disabled', true );
    } ).select2( {
        ajax: {
            url: users_ajax.root + 'my-plugin/v1/select2_users',
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: { 'X-WP-NONCE': users_ajax.nonce }
        },
        minimumInputLength: 2
    } );
} );
```

When all code put together, you'd get something like so:

[image]

Comment: I haven't tested this myself but overall this looks like it could/should work.  Nice work Sally CJ.  Hoping the OP can let us know if this works.

Comment: Thanks @TonyDjukic! I also hope the OP can test it soon.. :)

Comment: @SallyCJ awesome man! this worked like charm! thank you so much! you are genius!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the bounty, @MaulikVora! And I'm glad the solution worked for you. :)